# python window threading

Tags: python

I am importing in windows:

```
from threading import Thread
```

It gives me error as:

```
cannot import name Thread
```

Can anyone resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the python file in named `threading.py`? If yes, try to change the name.

Answer (score 2):

modify your code to look like this:

```
import threading
print "threading imported from", threading.__file__
```

If the first line fails it means your installation is somehow misconfigured or is missing this library. If the first line succeeds, the second should tell you what actual file is being loaded. Presumably this will show that it's importing the wrong file, and you can use that information to further debug the problem.

My guess is, you have a file named "threading.py" in your current directory, but that's just a guess based on insufficient information.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Console2>python
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from threading import Thread
>>>
```

Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me right, in older versions of python (2.4?) you *had* to do this:

```
import threading
foo = threading.Thread()  # or
class Foo(threading.Thread):
    pass
```

but you could not `from threading import Thread`